# Following directions on pairs in exploding kittens?

Tags: exploding-kittens

I haven't seen a clear answer to this: if you play a pair or three of a kind of cards with instructions (advanced rules) do you also follow the instructions on the cards as well as perform the card steal ?

For example, if I played three skip cards do I not only get to take a card of my choosing from my opponent AND skip the draw at the end of my turn ?  Or only take the card of my choosing ?

Most of what I've found are like this one: [Playing pairs of non-cat cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25723/playing-pairs-of-non-cat-cards) - just a reiteration of the 'advanced rules'.

Answer (score 6):

As per the VERY first paragraph in the "Special combos (for advanced play)" section on the rules:

> When you play combos, **ignore the instructions on the cards** and do the following instead:

Therefore, in the situation you presented, you would still be required to draw a card to end your turn as you played a Three of a Kind, not a skip card. If you had the remaining skip card, you could play it separately to end your turn without drawing a card.

Comment: Ha - I totally missed that in the included instructions!